# Get the default value of a variable

Tags: 8

I want to display the default value of a variable when no value is set. I checked the Drupal 8 documentation pages, but I couldn't find any information about the default value.

> In Drupal 7 if variable value is not set then default value is displayed.
>
> ```
> variable_get('variable_name', 'hello');
> ```
>
> If "variable_name" is not set at that time, *hello* will be returned.

Now for Drupal 8 I am trying the following way.

```
$config = $this->configFactory->get('module_name.settings');

$config->get('variable_name', 'hello'),
```

I am not getting *hello*.

Comment: See core/modules/forum/config/install/forum.settings.yml
You type it once, in defaults as chx mentions

Comment: technically one could do `$config->get('variable_name') ?: 'hello'` but it's best practice to create a config install file as the accepted answer mentions. This way you don't need to write conditionals when retrieving the value.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Your module ships with a default config; it gets installed. Now your config has the default value; if someone overrides it, it doesn't have one anymore. `$config->get('foo')` doesn't have a default value.